# Expansion of perturbed pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory, pseudoinverse

I am looking to express the pseudo-inverse of a matrix,

$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{E}$

where $\mathbf{E}$ is a small random perturbation, as a series expansion. For a real and square matrix $\mathbf{B}$, I am aware that the Taylor expansion (to first order),

$\mathbf{B^{-1}} \approx \mathbf{A^{-1}}-\mathbf{A^{-1}}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{A^{-1}} $

is valid. However, I am dealing with a complex non-square matrix $\mathbf{B}$. Is the above expansion also valid for this case?

Links to any relevant texts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $B$ is an $m\times n$ matrix where $m\leq n$. Do you have a guarantee that $\operatorname{rank} B = n$?

Comment: $\mathbf{B}$ would be full rank, so i guess its rank would be $m$..? (Am i wrong in thinking that the rank of $\mathbf{B}$  can only be as great as the smallest dimension, i.e. $m$?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a guarantee that the matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ is a full rank matrix (you are right, the rank cannot exceed $m$ and $n$), then the pseudoinverse of the matrix $B$ is given by

$$
(A^T A)^{-1} A^T
$$
if $m\geq n$ and
$$
A^T(AA^T)^{-1}
$$
if $m < n$.

Hope that this helps, since you can now use the expansion for the inverse of the matrix $A^T A$ or $AA^T$.